# Nibbana: Not an Ultimate Reality or Ultimate Truth?

Tags: nirvana, abhidhamma, right-view

A certain Brahman (lay priest, as he uses this term) here told:

> Nibbana is simply what is experienced by the mind which is free from defilements and fetters. It is not an Ultimate Reality or Ultimate Truth.

So according this, Nibbana isn't real but something, a maybe 'unconditioned Mind' experianses, and mind is obiviously assumed to be real.

What did the Buddha told in regard of Nibbana and Mind?

"Nibbānaṃ anicca. Cittānaṃ saraṇaṃ hotu."?

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchange, other worldbinding trades or to entertain the mind, but for an escape to lasting freedom from debt]*

Comment: By the way, I updated my statement to say "Nibbana is simply what is experienced by the mind which is free from defilements and fetters. It is not an Ultimate Reality i.e. it's not an eternal state of existence." I meant Ultimate Reality from the Hindu sense of the term.

Comment: Most, when one is after an enemy, one actually becomes total the same... as soon as a view is grasped..

Answer (score 1):

"*Nirvāna has been described by the Buddha not as the ending of rebirth (jāti nirodho), but as the ending of the delusion of existence (bhava nirodho Nibbānaŋ), by awakening from the dream of existence (samma sambodhi).*" Page 57 from [here](https://buddhaoriginalteachings.blogspot.com/p/level-iii-sublime-eightfold-way.html)

"*The paradigm shift (nirodha samāpatti) where the meditator withdraws from the paradigm of existence (bhava) and gets established in the paradigm of experience (nirodha), brings about the freedom or liberation (vimutti) from emotional excitements (tanhā) and accompanying suffering (dukkha), ending in the imperturbable serenity, Nibbāna. This means the mind that was purified will never become polluted again*." Page 78 from [here](http://Th%20e%20paradigm%20shift%20(nirodha%20sam%C4%81patti)%20where%20the%20meditator%20withdraws%20from%20the%20paradigm%20of%20existence%20(bhava)%20and%20gets%20established%20in%20the%20paradigm%20of%20experience%20(nirodha),%20brings%20about%20the%20freedom%20or%20liberation%20(vimutti)%20from%20emotional%20excitements%20(tanh%C4%81)%20and%20accompanying%20suff%20ering%20(dukkha),%20ending%20in%20the%20imperturbable%20serenity,%20Nibb%C4%81na.%20Th%20is%20means%20the%20mind%20that%20was%20purifi%20ed%20will%20never%20become%20polluted%20again.)

Comment: What a declared misinterpretation of the Buddha, saying mind is the ultimate reality and Nibbana a word for it's experiance... Outstanding nonsens... 'Is not ending of birth...', and uncountable stated otherwise by the Sublime Buddha. That's fist grade eternalists philosophy... and this from a disciple and his followers...

Answer (score 0):

Nibbāna is Nirodha-AriyaSacca.

Nirodha is finishing of arising and arising's causes.

Ariya is Ultimate Meditated People.

Sacca is Truth.

Recite and memorize DN MahāsatipatthānaSutta SaccaPabba in Pali everyday for more information.

Comment: Useless answer, like most. If to greedy to sacrifices time, why answer at all young householder?